# Adjust all nested lists to the same length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am referring to this this specific answer [Making nested lists same length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12550978/8665351). Since I don't have the permissions to comment yet and answering with a question to that topic would violate the rules, I am asking a new question.

I don't fully understand the answer.
In my understanding the iterator `row` in the for-loop is usually an integer value which iterates over each element in `myList`. So how is it possible to use `len(row)` as part of the condition since it is just an integer? Is there something I am  missing?

I have tried to apply this solution to my code but as expected I receive an error saying

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
 args = ("object of type 'int' has no len()",)
 with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of TypeError object>
```

referring to this line

```
row.extend(['null'*(len(maxSS7) - len(row))])
```

Further I don't understand the use of `.extend` with `row` which is the iterator and not a list.

Here is the relevant part from the answer.

```
maxLen = max(map(len, myList))
for row in myList:
    if len(row) < maxLen:
        row.extend(...)
```

A brief walkthrough would be greatly appreciated.

Or maybe there is a better way to adjust the lengths of all nested list to same length.

Comment: Nope, `row` isn't an int. It's also not an iterator. It's just a list, which has a `len`.

Comment: Try `for row in myList: print('Row:', row)` to see what `row` actually is.

Comment: Alright. Basically `for` every list in `nest` do something. I understand. That is pretty helpful. So why is it throwing an error like mentioned in the question?

Comment: You correctly identified the protocol. Good job on posting another question instead of getting clobbered for doing something you aren't supposed to. Have a +1

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Thanks.I had some not so good posts, since I was still learning the rules. I am getting there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, lets go through it line by line. Personally I don't think `map` is very idiomatic in Python so I would write this:

```
maxLen = max(map(len, myList))
```

As a generator expresion:

```
max_len = max(len(item) for item in my_list)
```

The second version is almost plain English: let `max_len` be the maximum value among the length of each item in `my_list`.

The best way to understand something in Python is just fire up the REPL and try it. So if you have `my_list` as a list of lists:

```
my_list = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

The above will get you the length of the largest item: 3

Now you want to make every item the same size. How can you do that? One way is to append `None` items to it. For each item in the list, you test if the length of the item is smaller then the largest item in the list and it is almost plain English:

```
for item in list:                # for each item in the list
    while len(item) < max_len:   # while the item length is smaller than 3
        item.append(None)        # append None to the item
```

You may want to do a bit of premature optimization and call `extend` once instead of calling `append` several times because you think performance will be better this way (but you can't really tell it unless you have profiled both solutions):

```
for item in list:
    if len(item) < max_len:
        item.extend([None] * (max_len - len(item)))
```

Now what is going on here? In Python, `list + list` concatenates two copies of list, and `list * 3` is the same as `list + list + list`. So in the first iteration of the for loop, `item` is `[1]`, `len(item)` is 1 and `max_len - len(item)` is `3 - 1`. Finally, `[None] * 2` is `[None, None]` so after the call to `extend` the first item will be `[1, None, None]`. Same thing for the second item, its length is 2, 3 minus 2 is one and it will end up as `[1, 2, None]`. The 3rd item has the same length as `max_len` (3) so the if condition is false. The result will be:

```
[[1, None, None], [1, 2, None], [1, 2, 3]]
```

All lists in the list of lists now have the same size, 3. For the sake of completion, for such a small list the `extend` version is less than 1  microsecond faster than the `append` one so barely worth the trouble (1.64 µs versus 1.7 µs in Python 3.6 running on my Mac).

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty detailed and a great walkthrough., Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in myList:
```

You created a variable called `row` which refers to an item within `myList`.

`row` is an integer.

You can get len of a list. Not an integer.

You messed up making your list. Troubleshoot it by printing the myList and seeing what the structure looks like so you know what you're iterating through cause it's probably not a 2d list.